# Rails seed.rb without controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails project I created a model called `team_category` but I don't have a controller with this one.

I have inside a field `string:category` and I want to know how I can fill my table with the `seed.rb` file without using any controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeding really has nothing to do with controllers. You are filling the DB with pre-defined data, and your models are those that correspond to the database's structure.

seed.rb is quite simply a ruby file and you can fill with any ruby code you like. Then run it from the console like this: `rake db:seed`.

Note that seed.rb has to be manually run, it is not run every time a client makes a request, like controller code (of course you can make it run whenever you want, but you really don't want to do that. Remember the Rails motto: convention over configuration).

Please see this link to learn more: 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data